# Finding common value in two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with a query where i need to get all the common values in column #2 that are for every element of column #1.

For example:

```
Column #1 Column #2
-------------------
21          2.00
21          5.00
21          6.00
21          8.00
21          9.00

41          2.00
41          3.00
41          4.00
41          5.00
41          6.00
41          9.00

52          2.00
52          5.00
52          9.00
52         10.00
52         20.00

Result
-------------------
2.00
5.00
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Juan Alvarez

Comment: How is `2.00` in the results?  It's not in column 2 for `52`...`9.00` is in all 3 though.

Comment: Are you sure the example is correct ? The 2.00 value does not appear for every value in column #1.

Comment: I think you need to look at your example again. It makes no sense that 2.00 is listed in the results while 6.00 is not.  Can you explain what you want a bit more clearly?

Comment: A possible answer might be that it was the answer for a different exercise in the workbook.

Comment: Another version is, the query should return distinct values of column #2 that share some *common property* as applied to 'every element of column #1'. In that case the common property of `2.00` and `5.00` could be that they represent the minimum values found in every group.

Comment: Old question, edited the example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column2
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY column2
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1) FROM YourTable)
```